# call two function by Inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

I'm new for OOPS JavaScript. Be clear. See my JavaScript code here,

```
function a(){
    this.first = "Kar";
}
function b(){
    this.last = "Sho";
}
function c(){
    this.getName = function(){
        return this.first+this.last;
    }
}

c.prototype.u = new a();
c.prototype.v = new b();

var d = new c();

alert(d.getName());
```

Here, I'm getting following output,

```
NaN
```

But I want to print **KarSho**. Where is problem?

I know following method,

```
b.prototype = new a();
c.prototype = new b();
```

Actually what I want is, just call **a** and **b** in **c**. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.prototype.u = new a();
c.prototype.v = new b();
```

Creates instances of the `a` and `b` object on the `c.v` and `c.u` prototype properties.

To access them, you would call them by:

```
function c(){
  this.getName = function(){
    return this.v.first + this.u.last;
  }
}
```

This is not really inheritance, but rather assigning of properties.

Answer (score 2):

Call both `a` and `b` in the `c` constructor.

```js
function a(){
    this.first = "Kar";
}
function b(){
    this.last = "Sho";
}
function c(){
    a.call(this);
    b.call(this);
    this.getName = function(){
        return this.first+this.last;
    }
}

var d = new c();

alert(d.getName());
```